# Prevent Angular Material dialog from disabling background controls when in use

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, dialog, draggable

I have an Angular draggable dialog and I want the user to still be able to use the website when the dialog is open (scroll, click on buttons etc.) By default, the dialog prevent background control.

Is there anyway to do this with an Angular Mat dialog? If not, what would you recommend I use instead of an Angular Mat Dialog?

I haven't included my code, just because it's a standard Angular Mat Dialog, nothing fancy, so I didn't think it necessary. But if it helps, let me know and I can add my code too.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Angular Material, you can set to `false` the property `hasBackdrop`, from the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogConfig)

```js
this.dialog.open(YourDialogComponent, { width: '320px', hasBackdrop: false})
 .afterClosed()
 .subscribe()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. So this kind of works, but it causes the dialog to drag behind some of the other elements when moving it. I still want the dialog to be at the front, but I also want to be able to interact with elements outside the dialog. I've tried playing around with the z-index to no avail.

Comment: If I limit the width, it just restricts the area where I can drag the dialog. I want to be able to drag the dialog all over the page and still be able to interact with the background